XMonad with Conky as a dock
I am attempting to use Conky as a dock in XMonad so that layouts will leave space for the Conky window and not overlap the Conky window. I have used the default .conkyrc that gets generated with conky -C and tried both own_window_type set as desktop and dock. In my xmonad.hs I have the following relevant parts
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
...
myManageHook = composeAll
    [
    className =? "Conky" --> doIgnore
    ]
...
myLayout = avoidStruts (...)
...
myConfig = def
...
, layoutHook = myLayout
, manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageDocks
...
main = xmonad . ... . docks $ myConfig

My desire is for XMonad to leave a column in all layouts such that the Conky window is present at all times and other windows will be behind Conky. However, new windows cover Conky completely.
I am planning to use Conky as a system monitor, utilizing cpugraph especially. I am not opposed to using dzen2, but I am not very familiar with it.
Is there any config I am missing to make this possible?

Have a look at the XMonad.Layout.Monitor layout modifier.

@pmf Thanks, it put me on the right and I ended up dedicating a gap in my layout for conky with XMonad.Layout.Gaps where I specify the size of the conky window. I would have liked for the size to be detected automatically, but this works for the moment.
